# making input type time for 24 format jq

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to make something line  but in 24 format not 12 format so i made input field with 2 arrows up and down when i click on up the inc() function is called and down the dec() function is called but my problem is these functions inc and dec hours how can i make something that make this for hours and minutes .

```js
function inc() {
  var admissionTime = $(".add-time").val();
  var hours = parseInt(admissionTime.split(":")[0]); ///before
  var minutes = parseInt(admissionTime.split(":")[1]);
  hours = hours + 1;

  if (hours <= 24) {
    var bb = hours + ':' + minutes;
    $(".add-time").val(bb);
  } else {
    var bb = 00 + ':' + 00;
    $(".add-time").val(bb);
  }
}

function dec() {
  var admissionTime = $(".add-time").val();
  var hours = parseInt(admissionTime.split(":")[0]); ///before
  var minutes = parseInt(admissionTime.split(":")[1]); ///after
  minutes = minutes - 1;
  if (minutes <= 60) {
    $(".add-time").val() = hours + ':' + minutes;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 timer-container">
  <label>Time *</label>
  <div class="timer">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-up " id="incease" aria-hidden="true" onclick="inc()">Inc</i>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down" id="decrease" aria-hidden="true" onclick="dec()">Dec</i>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="time" value="{{admission.time}}" class="add-time form-control required">
</div>
```

Comment: qstion not clear no punctuation no easy to understand pls put some effort in yr question and more clear pls

Comment: Can you update your question and flatten admission.time so we know what you're using for an input?

Comment: In dec() you certainly can't set val() = something.

Answer (score 5):

You use Bootstrap and jQuery. Therefore it is reasonable to use Bootstrap Datepicker with [custom format](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#custom-formats). In the following example I use hours, minutes and seconds components. But if you need to display hours and minutes only, then you could use `'HH:mm'` format value.

```js
$('[name="time"]').datetimepicker({
  format:'HH:mm:ss'
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 timer-container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group date">
      <input class="form-control required" type="text" name="time" value="23:06:35" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All possible values of format are listed in the [momentjs documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Comment: @Alexander the console tells me that >> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function

Comment: @marwam, include JS in following order to your page: **moment.js**, **jQuery**, **bootstrap.js** and **bootstrap-datetimepicker.js**. See `<script>` tags in my answer.

Comment: @marwam, how do you do? Has moment.js inclusion helped you?

Answer (score 2):

You need two sets of arrows to do this, one for the hours and one for the minutes.
This means you need four event handlers, one for each arrows.
The rest is simple math.

Since your question doesn't include much CSS, I played with it in order to position the arrows.
And I assumed you use Bootstrap.

```js
// Arrow setup
var timeInput = $(".add-time");
var upHour = timeInput.siblings(".up.hour");
var downHour = timeInput.siblings(".down.hour");
var upMinute = timeInput.siblings(".up.minute");
var downMinute = timeInput.siblings(".down.minute");

var timeInputPos = timeInput.offset();
upHour.css({"top":timeInputPos.top+4,"left":timeInputPos.left+3});
downHour.css({"top":timeInputPos.top+16,"left":timeInputPos.left+3});
upMinute.css({"top":timeInputPos.top+4,"left":timeInputPos.left+56});
downMinute.css({"top":timeInputPos.top+16,"left":timeInputPos.left+56});

// TIME
var actualTime = timeInput.val();
var actualHour = parseInt(actualTime.split(":")[0]);
var actualMinute = parseInt(actualTime.split(":")[1]);

// Handlers
upHour.on("click",function(){
  actualHour++;
  if(actualHour>23){
    actualHour=0;
  }
  updateTime();
});
downHour.on("click",function(){
  actualHour--;
  if(actualHour<0){
    actualHour=23;
  }
  updateTime();
});
upMinute.on("click",function(){
  actualMinute++;
  if(actualMinute>59){
    actualMinute=0;
  }
  updateTime();
});
downMinute.on("click",function(){
  actualMinute--;
  if(actualMinute<0){
    actualMinute=59;
  }
  updateTime();
});

function updateTime(){
  var prefixMinute="";
  var prefixHour="";
  if(actualHour<10){
    prefixHour="  ";
  }
  if(actualMinute<10){
    prefixMinute="0";
  }
  timeInput.val(prefixHour+actualHour+":"+prefixMinute+actualMinute);
}
```

```css
.add-time{
  width:4.3em !important;
  cursor:initial !important;
}
.up,.down{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:2;
  cursor:pointer !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 timer-container">
  <label>Time *</label>
  <div class="timer">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-up up hour" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down down hour" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    
    <i class="fa fa-caret-up up minute" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down down minute" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    
    <input type="text" name="time" value="13:00" class="add-time form-control required" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's what i'm asking for but i want to make what you did with 2 arrows up, and down because in this way it's not good for me to make 4 arrows and i don't know how to make it maybe by highlight the hours 10 and press up button to increase and the same for minutes

Comment: For the user point of view, what you want to do is less intuitive. And from the coding point of view, more complex. I would reconsider that.